# Too much space in the section

Tags: spacing, sectioning

My problem is the next, I have too much space to finish a `\section` and start the other section

[image]

the code is:

```
...ropagaci\'on, as\'i solamente la luz que sea paralela al eje de polarizaci\'on atravesara el polarizador. 

\section{\'Angulo de Brewster}
\subsection{Teor\'ia}

Entendemos como \'angulo de Brewster como el \'angulo que hay entre la direcci\'on de propagaci\'on y la...
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that we can compile to reproduce your output. For example, which document class are you using? Also, to format code properly, begin each line using four spaces.

Comment: sorry if my question is bad reads, i'm new and my english is no very good

Comment: You probably have a big object in the next page, possibly a `\begin{figure}[H]` or a long display with `align` or similar.

Comment: It is OK if your English is not perfect. Please include everything in your `.tex` file code example from the `\documentclass` to the `\end{document}` so that we can see what document class you are using and which packages if any.

Comment: sorry, but How can i add my .tex? if u can help me please

Comment: @aaron.c Edit your question and add a minimal complete document that reproduces your problem.

Comment: unclear without further information. Could be `\raggedbottom` business, but who knows? Vote to Close